# Difference between CREATE and VARIABLE

Tags: forth, gforth

What is the difference between the two words CREATE and VARIABLE?

For example, in this code:

```
VARIABLE MYARRAY 2 CELLS ALLOT
170 340 220 MYARRAY ! MYARRAY 1 CELLS + ! MYARRAY 2 CELLS + !

CREATE MYARRAY 220 , 340 , 170 ,
```

In both cases the result is the same in memory. Is it right? When should I use one in place of the other? And why?

Comment: CREATE does not allot any bytes for a value rather VARIABLE automatically allocates a cell in memory

Answer (score 4):

Right, `VARIABLE` allocates one cell of memory.  Also, a standard program may not assume that it can 
add data after the variable, see [Contiguous regions](http://lars.nocrew.org/dpans/dpans3.htm#3.3.3.2).

`CREATE` does not by itself allocate any memory, but starts a contiguous region which can be extended.  And, it's the only word which a standard program may use in combination with `DOES>`.

The difference may be mostly stylistic (unless you use `DOES>` or care deeply about the standard).  It's more clear to a reader that `VARIABLE` is a plain variable.  `CREATE` can be any type of data structure.

If you want an initialised variable, you can use either `VARIABLE FOO  BAR FOO !` or `CREATE FOO  BAR ,`.  I don't see that either alternative is preferred over the other to a significant degree.